# Asp.Net MVC passing model via ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've got a model that I'd like to use to generate/bind a pop-up form that remains hidden on a page until needed for use.

```
<table id="dlgNewEdit" class="vtableform hide">
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.CustomLabelFor(m => new NewEditModel().Name)</td>
        <td>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => new NewEditModel().OemEquipmentMakeId)
            @Html.CustomTextBoxFor(m => new NewEditModel().Name, new { @class = "focus w300" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => new NewEditModel().Name)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.CustomLabelFor(m => new NewEditModel().Description)</td>
        <td>
            @Html.CustomTextAreaFor(m => new NewEditModel().Description, new { @class = "w300" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => new NewEditModel().Description)
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Resulting in:

```
<table id="dlgNewEdit" class="vtableform hide">
    <tr>
        <td><label class="required" for="Name">* Name</label></td>
        <td>
            <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field OemEquipmentMakeId must be a number." data-val-required="The OemEquipmentMakeId field is required." id="OemEquipmentMakeId" name="OemEquipmentMakeId" type="hidden" value="0" />
            <input autocomplete="off" class="required tip focus w300" data-val="true" data-val-length="Cannot exceed 50 characters" data-val-length-max="50" data-val-required="Required" id="Name" maxlength="50" name="Name" title="Enter the make name" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="Description">Description</label></td>
        <td>
            <textarea class="w300 tip" cols="20" data-val="true" data-val-length="Cannot exceed 500 characters" data-val-length-max="500" id="Description" name="Description" rows="2" title="Enter a brief description">
</textarea>
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Description" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, I can't figure out any way to generate the correct form Ids/Names without using "new NewEditModel()" in all my expressions. Doing so works just fine, but it seems a bit verbose. I want my field names to exactly match my model properties because I want the model to bind in the following action which is called via jQuery ajax:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonNetResult New(NewEditModel model)
    {
    }
```

I tried created a variable:

```
var myModel = new NewEditModel();
```

using:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => myModel.OemEquipmentMakeId)
```

But that generates id/name "myModel.OemEquipmentMakeId" which doesn't bind in my action. Is there a way to do what I want in a different manor?

*** EDIT ***
Here is a more detailed representation of the view. Again, the model I was to pass back and forth from the ajax form IS NOT the model bound to the page. It's a search result page. When the user clicks edit on the row, I fetch the record via ajax from the server and display in a popup. Clicking OK on the popup calls the action via ajax. That is where I want the model to be bound correctly in the action. bootdialog is a custom jQuery plugin I adapted from bootbox (Bootstrap modal plugin) that loads DOM content into a popup.

```
@model IndexModel

@section startupscripts
{
    $('.command-add').on('click', function() { addMake(); })

    $('#SearchGrid')
        .on('click', '.command-edit', function() { editMake($(this).data('id')); })
        .on('click', '.command-delete', function() { deleteMake($(this).data('id')); });

    filter(@Model.Criteria.Page.GetValueOrDefault(1), '@Model.Criteria.SortExpression');
}

@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _currentPage, _currentSort;
        function filter(page, sort) {
            ...
        }

        function resetSearch() {
            ...
        }

        function addMake() {

            notify();

            bootdialog.prompt($('#dlgNewEdit'),
                {
                    title: 'New OEM Equipment Make',
                    formAction: '@Url.Action("New")',
                    formMethod: 'POST',
                    showClose: false,
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            label: 'OK',
                            value: true,
                            isPrimary: true,
                            callback: function (data) {
                                notify('success', 'New OEM equipment make \'' + data.name + '\' successfully created');
                                filter(_currentPage, _currentSort);
                            }
                        },
                        { label: 'Cancel', value: false }
                    ]
                });
        }

        function editMake(id) {

            notify();

            var bError = false;

            // Load the information from the DB
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Edit")',
                data: { id: id },
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                type: 'GET',
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    notify('error', 'There was an error querying the database', error);
                    bError = true;
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.errors) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.errors.length; i++)
                            notify('error', 'There was an error querying the database', data.errors[i].message);
                        bError = true;
                    } else {
                        $('#dlgNewEdit #@Html.IdFor(m => new NewEditModel().OemEquipmentMakeId)').val(id);
                        $('#dlgNewEdit #@Html.IdFor(m => new NewEditModel().Name)').val(data.data.name);
                        $('#dlgNewEdit #@Html.IdFor(m => new NewEditModel().Description)').val(data.data.description);
                    }
                }
            });

            if (bError) return;

            bootdialog.prompt($('#dlgNewEdit'),
                {
                    title: 'Edit OEM Equipment Make',
                    formAction: '@Url.Action("Edit")',
                    formMethod: 'POST',
                    showClose: false,
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            label: 'OK',
                            value: true,
                            isPrimary: true,
                            callback: function (data) {
                                notify('success', 'OEM equipment make \'' + data.name + '\' successfully updated');
                                filter(_currentPage, _currentSort);
                            }
                        },
                        { label: 'Cancel', value: false }
                    ]
                });
        }

        function deleteMake(id) {
            notify();
            bootdialog.confirm(
                'Are you sure you want to delete this OEM equipment make?',
                { title: 'Delete OEM Equipment Make' },
                function (e) {
                    if (e) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            async: false,
                            url: '@Url.Action("Delete")',
                            data: AddAntiForgeryToken({ id: id }),
                            success: function (data) {
                                if (data.data != null) {
                                    notify('success', 'OEM equipment make \'' + data.data.name + '\' successfully deleted');
                                    filter(_currentPage, _currentSort);
                                } else {
                                    for (var i = 0; i < data.errors.length; i++)
                                        notify('error', 'There was an error deleting the OEM equipment make', data.errors[i].message);
                                }
                            },
                            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                                notify('error', 'There was an error deleting the OEM equipment make', error);
                            },
                            dataType: 'json'
                        });
                    }
                }
            );
        }

    </script>
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="span3">
        <div class="well well-side">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("SearchGrid", null, FormMethod.Get, new {id = "frmSearch"}))
            {
                <div class="vertical-control-group">
                    @Html.CustomLabelFor(m => m.Criteria.Name)
                    @Html.CustomTextBoxFor(m => m.Criteria.Name)
                </div>
                <div class="vertical-control-group-commands">
                    @Html.CustomLinkButton("Search", new { @class = "btn-primary", onclick = "filter(1, 'Name');", title = "Click to search" })
                    @Html.CustomLinkButton("Reset", new { onclick = "resetSearch();", title = "Click to reset" })
                </div>
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Criteria.Page)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Criteria.SortExpression)
            }
            <div class="vertical-control-group-divider"></div>
            <div class="vertical-control-group-commands">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-inverse tip command-add" title ="Create new make">New Make</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span9" id="SearchGrid">
        @{
            Html.RenderAction("Loading", "Master", new { area = "", text = "Loading makes. Please wait..." });  
        }
    </div>
</div>

<table id="dlgNewEdit" class="vtableform hide">
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.CustomLabelFor(m => new NewEditModel().Name)</td>
        <td>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => new NewEditModel().OemEquipmentMakeId)
            @Html.CustomTextBoxFor(m => new NewEditModel().Name, new { @class = "focus w300" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => new NewEditModel().Name)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.CustomLabelFor(m => new NewEditModel().Description)</td>
        <td>
            @Html.CustomTextAreaFor(m => new NewEditModel().Description, new { @class = "w300" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => new NewEditModel().Description)
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you include the rest of the view code? You should be able to replace the new NewEditModel() with m in each of the HtmlHelpers (as you've written it). My guess is that you haven't declared the model correctly in the view

Comment: That's the problem I'm facing. The model needed to be populated by my "pop-up" form is completely independent from the model being bound to the page...thus, I can't use m => m.Property.

Comment: You should show code more, are you using Partial View to load the Ajaxed data? How does your model look like?

Comment: @JasonButera that sounds like you're fighting the framework. Can you post the rest of the view? In that scenario (and without seeing the code) I guess I'd have the pop-up in a partial then call @Html.Partial("_ThePopUpFormPartialViewName", new NewEditModel())

Comment: @PaulD'Ambra. Thanks, I was going to go the Partial View route just like you described which I know will most likely work. I'm not really fighting the framework, I'm just making it more responsive. This pop-up is populated and shown in a pop-up modal when a user clicks on an Edit link in a grid. I take the id and hit an action that returns the model as json which I use to bind the pop-up via jQuery. Then, the OK button in the pop-up posts the pop-up form via ajax to an action expecting my model.

Comment: So then... you're not using a model to generate your view which is a server side thing, you're using JSON on the client? That's fine but the code you posted above isn't for that. That's what I mean about fighting the framework.

Comment: And now I've realised you already tried to create the model as a variable... that should work. You really need to post the whole view (unless it's massive in which case it's too massive ;-))

Answer (score 0):

I've just spun up an MVC3 project and added this as the Index view.

```
@using MvcApplication3.Models
@model NewEditModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Name)
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    }
</div>
```

in the HomeController I added:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(NewEditModel model)
    {
        //model contains the name from the view
        return View();
    }
}
```

Values posted from the form appear in the model.

So no need for `new NewEditModel()`

---

So based on your View I'd still recommend a partial view.

Pull just the table into a Partial View for example called "_SearchTable", set the Model and use the `m => m.Property` syntax, then in your view you would simply replace the table with `@Html.Partial("_SearchTable", new NewEditModel())`

So a new partial view:

```
@model NewEditModel
<table id="dlgNewEdit" class="vtableform hide">
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.CustomLabelFor(m => m.Name)</td>
        <td>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.OemEquipmentMakeId)
            @Html.CustomTextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "focus w300" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.CustomLabelFor(m => m.Description)</td>
        <td>
            @Html.CustomTextAreaFor(m => m.Description, new { @class = "w300" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Description)
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and your Index view becomes:

```
@model IndexModel

@section startupscripts
{
    $('.command-add').on('click', function() { addMake(); })

    $('#SearchGrid')
        .on('click', '.command-edit', function() { editMake($(this).data('id')); })
        .on('click', '.command-delete', function() { deleteMake($(this).data('id')); });

    filter(@Model.Criteria.Page.GetValueOrDefault(1), '@Model.Criteria.SortExpression');
}

@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _currentPage, _currentSort;
        function filter(page, sort) {
            ...
        }

        function resetSearch() {
            ...
        }

        function addMake() {

            notify();

            bootdialog.prompt($('#dlgNewEdit'),
                {
                    title: 'New OEM Equipment Make',
                    formAction: '@Url.Action("New")',
                    formMethod: 'POST',
                    showClose: false,
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            label: 'OK',
                            value: true,
                            isPrimary: true,
                            callback: function (data) {
                                notify('success', 'New OEM equipment make \'' + data.name + '\' successfully created');
                                filter(_currentPage, _currentSort);
                            }
                        },
                        { label: 'Cancel', value: false }
                    ]
                });
        }

        function editMake(id) {

            notify();

            var bError = false;

            // Load the information from the DB
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Edit")',
                data: { id: id },
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                type: 'GET',
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    notify('error', 'There was an error querying the database', error);
                    bError = true;
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.errors) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.errors.length; i++)
                            notify('error', 'There was an error querying the database', data.errors[i].message);
                        bError = true;
                    } else {
                        $('#dlgNewEdit #@Html.IdFor(m => new NewEditModel().OemEquipmentMakeId)').val(id);
                        $('#dlgNewEdit #@Html.IdFor(m => new NewEditModel().Name)').val(data.data.name);
                        $('#dlgNewEdit #@Html.IdFor(m => new NewEditModel().Description)').val(data.data.description);
                    }
                }
            });

            if (bError) return;

            bootdialog.prompt($('#dlgNewEdit'),
                {
                    title: 'Edit OEM Equipment Make',
                    formAction: '@Url.Action("Edit")',
                    formMethod: 'POST',
                    showClose: false,
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            label: 'OK',
                            value: true,
                            isPrimary: true,
                            callback: function (data) {
                                notify('success', 'OEM equipment make \'' + data.name + '\' successfully updated');
                                filter(_currentPage, _currentSort);
                            }
                        },
                        { label: 'Cancel', value: false }
                    ]
                });
        }

        function deleteMake(id) {
            notify();
            bootdialog.confirm(
                'Are you sure you want to delete this OEM equipment make?',
                { title: 'Delete OEM Equipment Make' },
                function (e) {
                    if (e) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            async: false,
                            url: '@Url.Action("Delete")',
                            data: AddAntiForgeryToken({ id: id }),
                            success: function (data) {
                                if (data.data != null) {
                                    notify('success', 'OEM equipment make \'' + data.data.name + '\' successfully deleted');
                                    filter(_currentPage, _currentSort);
                                } else {
                                    for (var i = 0; i < data.errors.length; i++)
                                        notify('error', 'There was an error deleting the OEM equipment make', data.errors[i].message);
                                }
                            },
                            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                                notify('error', 'There was an error deleting the OEM equipment make', error);
                            },
                            dataType: 'json'
                        });
                    }
                }
            );
        }

    </script>
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="span3">
        <div class="well well-side">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("SearchGrid", null, FormMethod.Get, new {id = "frmSearch"}))
            {
                <div class="vertical-control-group">
                    @Html.CustomLabelFor(m => m.Criteria.Name)
                    @Html.CustomTextBoxFor(m => m.Criteria.Name)
                </div>
                <div class="vertical-control-group-commands">
                    @Html.CustomLinkButton("Search", new { @class = "btn-primary", onclick = "filter(1, 'Name');", title = "Click to search" })
                    @Html.CustomLinkButton("Reset", new { onclick = "resetSearch();", title = "Click to reset" })
                </div>
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Criteria.Page)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Criteria.SortExpression)
            }
            <div class="vertical-control-group-divider"></div>
            <div class="vertical-control-group-commands">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-inverse tip command-add" title ="Create new make">New Make</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span9" id="SearchGrid">
        @{
            Html.RenderAction("Loading", "Master", new { area = "", text = "Loading makes. Please wait..." });  
        }
    </div>
</div>

@Html.Partial("_SearchTable", new NewEditModel())
```